# Should posts asking multiple questions be split up?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

A couple of questions have been asked recently (including one of mine it turns out) which are really asking multiple questions. For example:

- [How can one determine whether a LiPo battery is going bad?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/453/how-can-one-determine-whether-a-lipo-battery-is-going-bad)
- [How do I model a robot?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/436/how-do-i-model-a-robot/444#444)

Should these be split into multiple posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how related the two questions are and if it is extremely likely that someone knowing the answer to one of them will know the answer to the other. If the two questions are "Is X true? If so, why?" or "Is this a problem? How do I fix it?" (eg, the LiPo question) are *generally* fine in one post. Sometimes, splitting such posts makes very little sense (and can end up in one being closed as a duplicate.)--especially in the "Is X true? If so, why?" case.

The second one needs splitting or pruning (though, since you've answered it already, it no longer "needs" splitting).

The general modus operandi is that you ask the user to either (a) split the question, or (b) prioritize and ask only one main question (and possibly a closely related supplementary one)